# How can I change a cursor in roblox studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I am doing a roblox horror game project with a few friends and we want to test changing the cursor for the entire game. I found another question on a different forum that used to work but because of Roblox updating, it doesn't work. So I tried to modify the code. My code looks like this:

```
RepeatValue = script.RepeatValue.Value

repeat

    local mouse = game.Players.LocalPlayer:GetMouse()

    mouse.Icon = 'http://www.roblox.com/asset?id=7190557652'

    wait(0.1)
    RepeatValue = (RepeatValue - 1)

until RepeatValue == 0
```

But it doesn't change the cursor. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: does the example from the manual work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are running this in a local script because you can only get the mouse from the client, and not from the server.

First of all,

> http://www.roblox.com/asset?id=7190557652

doesn't exist. Try it again from an existing link, as this may be the cause of your problem.

Secondly, why did you put it in a loop?

You can just set it directly:

```
local mouse = game.Players.LocalPlayer:GetMouse()

mouse.Icon = 'http://www.roblox.com/asset?id=7190557652'
```